# laravel query having union can't groupBy

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.8

I'm trying to sort comments. Each comment could have a parent_id in case it is a replay to another comment.

I need to order all the comments by parent_date and comment_date.

I have created this query:

```
$union = DB::table("press_comments as c2")
        ->select("c2.body", "c2.id", 'c2.parent_id', 'c2.created_at as ac', 'p.created_at as ap')
        ->join('press_comments as p', 'c2.parent_id', '=', 'p.id');


$comments = DB::table('press_comments as c1')
        ->select("c1.body", "c1.id", 'c1.parent_id', 'c1.created_at as ac', 'c1.created_at as ap')
       // ->where("parent_id", "=", 0)
        ->union($union)
        ->orderBy("ap","asc")
        ->orderBy( "ac","asc")
        ->groupBy('id')
        ->paginate();
```

But I  got too many lines: the groupBy seems not working on.

In plain mysql it works:

```
SELECT *
   FROM (   SELECT c1.id,
              c1.parent_id,
              c1.created_at ac,
              c1.created_at ap
       FROM press_comments c1
       UNION
       SELECT c2.id,
              c2.parent_id,
              c2.created_at ac,
              p.created_at ap
       FROM press_comments c2
       JOIN press_comments p
       ON c2.parent_id = p.id) c
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY c.ap, c.ac;
```

What I'm missing in my Laravel query?

Comment: group by does't make sense here. _you often use the GROUP BY clause with aggregate functions such as SUM, AVG, MAX, MIN, and COUNT._

Comment: it works in my MySql query, but in Laravel. How fix it?

Comment: $comments = DB::table('press_comments as c1')
        ->select("c1.body", "c1.id", 'c1.parent_id', 'c1.created_at as ac', 'c1.created_at as ap')
       // ->where("parent_id", "=", 0)
        ->union($union)
        ->orderByRaw('ap , ac')
        ->paginate();

Comment: Thanks @BUcorp but the issue is in GroupBy, I need to remove the extra rows.

Comment: mmm maybe if you try to separate : $c2 = DB::table("press_comments as c2")
        ->select("c2.body", "c2.id", 'c2.parent_id', 'c2.created_at as ac', 'p.created_at as ap')
        ->join('press_comments as p', 'c2.parent_id', '=', 'p.id');


$c1 = DB::table('press_comments as c1')
        ->select("c1.body", "c1.id", 'c1.parent_id', 'c1.created_at as ac', 'c1.created_at as ap');


$c = DB::select(DB::raw('*')
          ->union($c1)
          ->union($c2)
          ->orderBy("ap","asc")
          ->orderBy( "ac","asc")
          ->groupBy('id')
          ->paginate();